# When do we write a superscript before a symbol?

Tags: notation

In what contexts is it conventional to write $ ^a B$, and in those contexts what does it mean?

I remembering seeing this but I can't remember where. I believe we would expect $a$ to be a function here and $B$ to be a set, possibly with additional structure. I feel like I may have seen this in field theory to mean the elements of a field $B$ fixed by an automorphism $a$. I also think I've seen it in differential geometry. Regardless I can't find it in my references.

Comment: It's used in set theory, for example $ ^{\omega}{\omega}$ represents the set of all functions from $\omega$ (the positive integers) into ${\omega}.$ Also in denoting the [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) operation.

Comment: In that notation, which $\omega$ represents the domain and which represents the codomain? In other words let's say $S,T$ are sets and I wrote $^TS$. Would this be the set of functions from $S$ to $T$ or the other way around? Is it in fact conventional to generalize it that way?

Comment: $^{\tau}{\sigma}$ would be functions from $\tau$ to $\sigma$. This use in set theory is to distinguish the function space construction from cardinal or ordinal exponentiation,

Comment: To add to @Rob Arthan's comment (I've been away and didn't see your reply to my comment until just now), in most other areas of pure mathematics $S^T$ represents the set of functions from $T$ into $S.$ But as Rob pointed out, this can be ambiguous when working with cardinal and ordinal numbers (and these "numbers" represent certain sets).